# Freezing app when using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, freeze

I download a high amount of data from API and want to make it efficient so I get first 100 record in one asyncTask and then in another asyncTask get another several thousands(in 500 hundred portions) The `loadListAsynchronously();` looks identicall as loadData function without `content,progress,loadContent();` function but this functions are not the problem - without `loadListAsynchronously();` app runs smoothly after frezee when download first data. I tried add transaction but that does not help me.

```
private void loadData() {
        DottedProgressBar progressBar = (DottedProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadIngDots);
        progressBar.startProgress();
        content = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main) ;
        progress = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressPage) ;
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> read =new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            SharedPreferences  keyValues;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 keyValues = getSharedPreferences(Settings.MODEL_LAST_CALL, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                modelList = new ArrayList<>();

                Map<String,String> options= new HashMap<>();
                options.put("limit",String.valueOf(AMOUNT_OF_LOADED_modelS));


                ApiHelper.getModelWithParams(new Callback<ModelApiEnvelope>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelApiEnvelope> call, Response<ModelApiEnvelope> response) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"First call model Get response");
                     final   ModelApiEnvelope envelope = response.body();
                      if(envelope==null)
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.server_down_explanation),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else{
                        try {
                           final Dao<Model,Integer> modelDAO  = getHelper().getmodelDAO();
                           final Dao<Submodel,Integer> submodelDAO=getHelper().getsubmodelDAO();
                            TransactionManager.callInTransaction(getHelper().getConnectionSource(),
                                    new Callable<Void>() {
                                        public Void call() throws Exception {
                        modelList=envelope.getData();
                                            Log.i(TAG,"LoadData loop Start");
                        for( final model m: modelList){
                            m.setLogo(m.getLogo()+"?width="+width/2+"&height="+height);
                            m.setLanguage(m.getLanguage().substring(0,2));
                            if(m.getLanguage().equals("uk"))
                                m.setLanguage("ua");
                            if(m.getsubmodels().size()!=0){
                                    for(final submodel e: m.getsubmodels()){
                                        e.setLanguage(m.getLanguage());
                                        submodelDAO.createOrUpdate(e);
                                    }
                                  }
                            try {
                                                modelDAO.createOrUpdate(m);
                               }catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
                        }

                                            return null;}
                                    });
                            if(envelope.getData().isEmpty()){
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                editor.putString(Settings.model_LAST_CALL , Long.toString(time));
                                editor.apply();
                            }
                           else
                                loadListAsynchronously();
                        }  catch (SQLException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG," message "+e.getMessage()) ; e.printStackTrace();
                        }}
                        loadContent();
                        content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<modelApiEnvelope> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"ERROR"+ t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.server_down_explanation),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        loadContent();


                    }
                },MainActivity.this,options, keyValues.getString(lang,"0"));
           return null;
            }
   @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
             super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         }

         @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }
    };
    read.execute();
}
```

UPDATE: Method Trace added
[image]

UPDATE 2: Removing the transaction solve my problem. It seems that the making transaction for thousands saveings into database freeze Ui.

Comment: Please show how you call/execute your AsyncTask.

Comment: You cannot call functions in doInbackGround which have callback functions as parameters. You cannot wait for onResponse() to be triggered there.

Comment: added  async task call. So i need to refactor in something like this? show progressView->api_call->on response(run asyncTask to load data and in the end of the loop hide progressView)?

Comment: Don't understand a word of that. Better just dont do the things i told you to do not.

Answer (score 0):

Callback in Retrofit1 and AsyncTask are not compatible. You have to modify your API interface from something like this :

```
public interface Api {
    void getModelWithParams(Callback<Something> callback);
}
```

To this :

```
public interface Api {
    Something getModelWithParams();
}
```

Then Retrofit will not provide async execution support and you can execute that row method inside AsyncTask.doInBackground method.

Other option is to stay with that interface definition and just call Retrofit method directly (without AsyncTask wrapping). The question is if your further logic is not heavy, because onResponse will be executed on UI Thread which cause your freezes and in general is root cause of your problem.